# Application creates multiple CDI-Beans by mistake

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi

i'm absolutely baffled. I have a standard, old school EJB-CDI-JSF-Hibernate JavaEE Application, running on a JBoss AS 7.1. Furthermore my structure is an absolut standard structure. I have JSF-Sites, which access my CDI Beans. The CDI Beans are holding a reference to one of my entities, the EJBs are used as DAOs. One of my beans is this CommissionController. It works absolutely fine. Only one instance is created for one user.

```
package controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.extern.java.Log;
import entities.Commission;

@SessionScoped
@Data
@Log
@Named
public class CommissionController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8452887234021054225L;

    @Inject
    private UserController userController;

    @Inject
    private CartController cartController;

    private Commission commission;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        commission = new Commission();
        log.info("new CommissionController instance");

    }

    public void makeNewCommission() {
        commission.setCart(cartController.getCart());
        commission.setOrderDate(new Date());
        commission.setOrderer(userController.getUser());
        cartController.clearCart();
        log.info(commission.toString());
    }
}
```

Now i have a different bean, but it think it's the excact same structure:

```
package controller;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.extern.java.Log;
import entities.Article;
import entities.Cart;

@SessionScoped
@Data
@Log
@Named
public class CartController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 649140288918816488L;

    @Inject
    private UserController userController;

    @Inject
    private ArticleController articleController;

    private Cart cart;

    public void addToCart(Article article) {
        cart.getArticleList().add(article);
        cart.setSum(cart.getSum() + article.getPrice());
    }

    public void clearCart() {
        cart.getArticleList().clear();
        cart.setSum(0.0);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        log.info("bean destroyed");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        cart = new Cart();
        log.info("new CartController instance");
    }

    public void removeFromCart(Article article) {
        cart.getArticleList().remove(article);
        cart.setSum(cart.getSum() - article.getPrice());
    }

}
```

I can't explain it to myself, but the second bean is instanciated again and again and I can't store anything in it, because it get always a reference to another bean.

Please, help me to bring light in this mystery. If you need additional information, I would love to give it to you. Maybe, I have a big lack of understanding but for now, I can't help myself.

Comment: The number one reason for this occurrence, by accident using the SessionScoped annotation from JSF 2, is not the case here judging by the import statements. You didn't mistakenly had the wrong annotation on it, fixed it but it isn't properly redeployed to the server by any chance?

Comment: No, I would be glad if this was the mistake. The project is a SVN-project and the error also occurs by other users. Still I tried more than one time, to clean the project, to clean the server and so on.

Comment: I take it you're using JBoss 7.1 community - it is horribly outdated. Did you try upgrading the version of Weld in it? Perhaps you're running into a bug which has already been fixed. You could as an alternative try to run this on JBoss Wildfly, just to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you so much. We just tried to programm the context dependency injection manually and it work. Then, I tried WildFly 8.0.0 Final and it also worked fine. So, it seems as my beloved JBoss 7.1.0 is a bit buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gimby gave me the answer to this question. In fact, JBoss AS 7.1.0 Community Edition is outdated. With WildFly 8.0.0 Final, everything worked perfectly fine. So, if you're working with the fantastic possibilities of CDI, try WildFly instead of JBoss AS 7.1.0 Final Community.

Comment: You are also free to just upgrade Weld in JBoss 7.1 ;) But why use JBoss 7 when there is Wildfly which is nearly the same but better.